# Is there a windows implementation to python libsvn?

Tags: python, svn, hook, pre-commit

Because windows is case-insensitive and because SVN is case-sensitive and because VS2005 tends to rename files giving them the lower-case form which messes my repositories' history, I've tried to add the pre-commit hook script from http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/case-insensitive.py.
Sure enough, the script uses classes from python's libsvn ("from svn import repos, fs") which I fail to find compiled for Windows.
Is there an alternative? To libsvn or to the hook script?

Comment: This question was solved in a different way for me. I now use ankhsvn (http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) which has built in support for case collisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tigris.org's pre-complied python bindings for libsvn are a separate download. The latest as of Oct 27 could be found [here](http://subversion.tigris.org/files/documents/15/44104/svn-win32-1.5.4_py25.zip).

There are other binary SVN distributions listed [here](http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html#windows), and they probably have different policy for bundling the python bindings.

Comment: Thanks, your answer led me to the following page: http://www.subversionary.org/howto/using-check-case-insensitive-py-on-windows

Comment: Good luck with that. Upstream python bindings suck. Very. Badly. That's why there are two different alternative bindings.

Comment: @ddaa, you may need to read the question again, especially this part: '...the script uses classes from python's libsvn ("from svn import repos, fs") which I fail to find compiled for Windows'.

Answer (score 4):

There are two alternative Python bindings for libsvn:

- [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/).
- [subvertpy](https://launchpad.net/subvertpy).

Subvertpy is quite new and is written by the author of [bzr-svn](http://bazaar-vcs.org/BzrForeignBranches/Subversion): the transparent [svn](http://subversion.apache.org/) inter-operation bridge for [bzr](http://bazaar-vcs.org/).

For a while, bzr-svn used the upstream [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) Python bindings, and the author contributed a lot of bug fixes. It helped move the upstream python support for "horribly broken" to "painfully aggravating and unpythonic". So after wasting too many hours of his life to SWIG, the author decided to make his own bindings.